# Setting Stored Procedure as SQL Statement in jasper

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have this simple code:

```
JasperDesign jDes = JRXmlLoader.load("jasperfile.jrxml");
String sql = "Select * From table WHere address like 'St. Vincents College%'";
JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
newQuery.setText(sql);
jDes.setQuery(newQuery);
JasperReport jRep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jDes);
JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,conn);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jPrint);
```

so basically that print's the report. What I want is instead of `SELECT...` query, I want to use a stored procedure let's say:

```
ProcedureName:    GenerateReportByAddress
Parameter    :    personName
```

How can I use `CallableStatement` in jasper?

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call GenerateReportByAddress(?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "secret");
```

Reasons are:

```
- to make query of application encapsulated by calling only stored procedure
- to avoid SQL Injection. (because some address contains Single Quote)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jasper Reports` does not support stored procedures. Temp tables is the right approach. For more details see this blog entry:

[How To Call Stored Procedures From JasperReports](http://brianburridge.com/2006/06/04/how-to-call-stored-procedures-from-jasper-reports/)

and alternatively, You can bind `Jasper Reports` to a different datasource. See here:

[Java beans as Jasper Reports data source using JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://www.robertomarchetto.com/www/how_to_print_java_collections_in_jasper_reports_using_JRBeanCollectionDataSource)